# Recursive max int in array

Tags: c, array, recursion

I would like a review for this simple recursive algorithm which returns the largest int in an array of integers. I would like feedback on the transfer of state via the third parameter specifically. Please also note 2 things:

1. It must be recursive
2. This is not for production usage, but rather recursion practice

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max_val(int arr[], int length, int curr_max)
{
    if(length <= 0)
        return curr_max;

    if(curr_max < *arr)
    {
        curr_max = *arr;
    }
    arr++;
    return max_val(arr,length-1,curr_max);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2,73,39,5,8,62,9};
    printf("Max: %d\n", max_val(arr,7,0));  
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your code wrongfully prints "Max: 0" for  `arr[] = {-1, -2, -3}`

Answer (score 2):

Never omit "optional" braces, as you did for your first `if` statement.  That's a bad habit that will eventually lead to a coding accident.  If you feel compelled to omit braces, then at least [put the whole statement on the same line](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16530/51698).

You should avoid unnecessary mutation, as you did with `arr++`.  This is  especially important with an exercise in recursion: it is one of the principles of [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming).

The `curr_max` parameter is annoying and unnecessary.  It also leads to a bug with negative array members, when a poorly selected initial value is chosen.  (You should use `INT_MIN` from [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) instead of `0`.)  Furthermore, your base case is questionable: is the maximum of a zero-length array well defined?

### Suggested solution

```
#include <assert.h>

int max_val(int arr[], size_t length)
{
    assert(length > 0);
    if (length == 1) return arr[0];
    int max_tail = max_val(arr + 1, length - 1);
    return arr[0] > max_tail ? arr[0] : max_tail;
}
```

Comment: `if (length == 1) return arr[0];` and _Never omit "optional" braces_ do not play well together.

Comment: @vnp I also said that it’s acceptable if you put it all on the same line.